# Questions about certain components in a Delphi program

Tags: database, delphi, dataset, components

I have to understand a program which is written in Delphi. It has certain components where I do not understand for what they stand for:

(1) For what use are TJvMemoryData and TJvStrHolder?
The TJvStrHolder is used in a JvDBUltimGrid and the TJvMemoryData in following order of data connecting to a SQL-Database:

TAstaClientSocket -> TAstaClientDataSet -> TJvMemoryData -> TDataSource

(2) Is there documentation which can help me to understand what the componenets are doing?

I'm using Delphi 7.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of the program? These are JEDI components which are essentially undocumented. You'll have to read the source to work out what they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes are from the [JEDI Visual Component Library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) and a product from [Astatech](http://www.astatech.com/) respectively.

For JVCL you can find documentation in the [JVCL help wiki](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:JVCL_Packages), the [summary is here](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Visual_Component_Library).

For AstaTech I can't see whether it's their [Asta](http://www.astatech.com/innerpage.php?news_id=3) or their [ODBC driver toolkit for Delphi](http://www.astatech.com/innerpage.php?news_id=6) product, their website has very little details. Maybe you can ask them.
If you Google for the component names you find some occasional information, often from their [Astatech Yahoo groups mailing list](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/astatech/conversations/topics).
Note that you have ASTA version 3 ("ASTA 3 supports Delphi 5,6,7, Delphi 2006 and Delphi 2007.") and not 4.

Prepare for a lot of digging.

*FWIW*: JVCL is big, but you'll probably be able to find what you need. You don't say what the status of your product is, but judging from the quality of their web site and the little info I could find, removing the ASTA components may be an option. They only have email support (for registered users, I assume) and that Yahoo email list. Maybe you're lucky and have some documentation somewhere? (And you can still ask them)

Answer (score 0):

Those components whose name starts with Tjv are part of Delphi Jedi Component Library. You can find their oficial documentation here: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/Main_Page

Those components whose name starts with TAsta are part of Astatechs ASTA network library. You can find more information anout them on their oficial webpage here: http://www.astatech.com/Files/Asta25/help/index.php

Comment: The JEDI "documentation" is auto generated from the source. Since the source has practically no doc strings, this is not very useful. Or have things changed recently?

Comment: They have a kiwi styled documentation now which is maintained by comunity so you would probably find athleast basic descriptions for most things I gues. I personally don't use JEDI

Comment: You might think that. But when you actually look closer you will see very little of use. Last time I checked it was as good as undocumented.